# Search and delete lines matching a pattern along with comments in previous line if any

Tags: scripting, shell, unix-shell, command-line-interface

I have a requirement to write a shell script in csh to search and delete lines matching a pattern along with comments in previous line if any. For example if my file has the following lines

```
Shell script
#this is  a test
pattern1
format1
pattern2
format2
#format3
pattern3
```

If the search pattern is "pattern" The output should be as follows

```
Shell script
format1
format2
```

To be more precise the lines which have the pattern and the previous line if it begins with "#" should be deleted

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try it now. I think I fixed the problem.

Comment: It's a shame that "grep -v" can't be used to do this, but adding the "-B 1" argument does about the opposite of what you want.  Sigh.  Maybe an "invert" flag for -B / -A should be added to GNU grep some day?

Answer (score 0):

First of all [nobody should ever use `csh`](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) for anything - it's outdated and un- (not "under") powered. Secondly, I doubt it's up to the task. Third, it's much more likely that `awk`, `sed` or even Perl will be a much better tool for the task.

```
awk '/^#/ {printf line; line=$0"\n"; next} /pattern/ {line=""} ! /pattern/ {printf line; print; line=""}'
```

Edit: fixed script to handle comment lines correctly

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I tried to use the command but the result is not what i expected. The pattern and the comment are still there. The result I got is as follows

Shell script
#this is  a testpattern1
format1
pattern2
format2
#format3pattern3

I want the line with the pattern and the comment in the previous line to be deleted

Comment: I'm not sure if the example is visible as expected. "#this is a test" is in a line and each word after that is in a spaerate line

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I had made a mistake. The command works.
Thanks

Comment: Hi,

This command has some issues. If I change the file as follows

#header
#test
Shell script
#this is  a test
pattern1
format1
pattern2
format2
#format3
pattern3

The result is as follows

#testShell script
format1
format2


#header is deleted, #test and Shell script are merged. Please advise

Comment: I am tyying to incorporate the awk command into a shell script and its not working as expected. The variable for pattern is not being read. Any suggestions on this

Comment: The command i'm using in the cript is as follows

cat $filename | awk '/^#/ {printf line; line=$0"\n"; next} /$pattern/ {line=""} ! /$pattern/ {printf line; print; line=""}'

Comment: Use awk variable passing: `awk -v pattern=$pattern '.../pattern/...'`

Comment: By the way, don't forget to upvote and accept answer(s) to your questions if you find them useful.

Comment: I am using the following script where I pass the pattern and the filename as parameters

#!/usr/bin/csh

set pattern=$argv[1]
set filename=$argv[2]

nawk -v pattern=$pattern '/^#/ {printf line; line=$0"\n"; next} /pattern/ {line=""} ! /pattern/ {printf line; print; line=""}' $filename

awk '/^#/ {printf line; line=$0"\n"; next} /pattern/ {line=""} ! /pattern/ {printf line; print; line=""}' pettern=$pattern $filename

Both the awk commands are not working. However if I substitute the variable with the actual pattern it works.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention when I posted that comment about the variables. In order to use a variable for a match you have to use the match operator `~` instead of `//`. Something similar to `nawk -v pattern=$pattern '/^#/ {printf line; line=$0"\n"; next} $0 ~ pattern {line=""}` ...

Comment: I tied the following command and it is deleting more lines then expected

nawk -v pattern=$pattern '/^#/ {printf line; line=$0"\n"; next} $0 ~ pattern {line=""} ! $0 ~ pattern {printf line; print; li
ne=""}' $filename

Comment: Did you paste that here? There's a space in the middle of the last reference to the variable "line". Also, it should be `$0 !~ pattern` instead of putting the "!" first.

Comment: I have made the change and it works. Thanks for the help.
What should be the command if I want to delete all the comments in the lines before the pattern

For example if I have the following lines in my ile

#format
test
#format1
#format2
#format3
pattern

I should get the output as 

#format
test

Comment: how do I alter the following command to display lines which match a particaular pattern and the cmments before the line matchung the pattern

nawk -v pattern=$pattern '/^#/ {line=line$0"\n"; next}  $0 ~ pattern {line=""} $0 ~ pattern {printf line; print; line=""}' $filename

exomple of the file

#comment1
#comment2
pattern1
pattern2
pattern1

Result should be 

#comment1
#comment2
pattern1

pattern1

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better way to write this logically, but I think this might do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $previous_line = '';
while(<>) {
    if ( /pattern/ ) {
        if ( (! ($previous_line =~ /^#/)) && (! ($previous_line =~ /pattern/))) {
            print $previous_line;
        }
    } elsif (! ($previous_line =~ /pattern/)) {
        print $previous_line;
    }
    $previous_line = $_;
}
print $previous_line if not ($previous_line =~ /pattern/);
```

Basically, the loop is a line behind with the previous line.  It says it is okay to print the *previous line* if:

1. If The current line matches the pattern: Okay to print previous as long as the previous didn't also match pattern, or it was a comment.
2. If this line is not pattern, it is
   okay to print the previous line as
   long as it didn't match pattern.

You can just save the code in a file and use it like: `perl thefile.pl textfile_you_want_to_filter`

Comment: Exactly how I'd do it more or less in anything (shell, perl, etc.), the logic is what matters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner solution in Perl (not in C shell). You can modify the `/pattern/` regular expression in the middle.

```
perl -ne 'if(/^#/){$c=$_}elsif(!/pattern/){print$c,$_;$c=""}else{$c=""}' <file.in
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be shell scripted?

1. open file with vi
2. `:g/<pattern>/d`
3. repeat as necessary for additional
   pattern-types unless you can regex
   the pattern
4. `:g/^#/d`

can be effectively reproduced using sed if it has to be scripted

edit:

1.create file .sedscript:

```
/pattern/d
/^#/d
```

2.`sed -f .sedscript <inputfile> > <outputfile>`

This does not satisfy a requirement to delete the previous line, but your example doesn't seem to require that functionality.

Comment: It has to be scripted for reusability.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `sed` version. Some versions of `sed` may need parts of this separated into multiple `-e` clauses.

```
sed '$b;N;/^#.*\npattern.*$/ ! {P;D}; :c; $d; s/.*\n//;N;/^#.*\npattern.*$/ {bc}; /^pattern/d; D' patterns
```

Here's a script file version of that one-liner with comments:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

# Search for a combination of a comment followed by a pattern
# until that, print what you find.
$b
N
/^#.*\npattern.*$/ ! {
P
D
}

:c
# Got a comment and a pattern combination in pattern space.
# At the end of the file we simply exit
$d

# Else, we keep reading lines with `N' until we
# find a different one
s/.*\n//
N
/^#.*\npattern.*$/ {
bc
}

# Remove standalone lines that have "pattern"
/^pattern/d

# Remove the last instance of the combination
# and go back to the top
D
```

This is based on the script in `info sed` section 4.16 "Remove All Duplicated Lines" (uniq -u).

Comment: This command is not working

Comment: Using a variable or a literal?

Comment: If it's a variable, wrap it in single quotes: `sed '$b;N;/^#.*\n'$pattern'.*$/ ! {P;D}; ...`