# How to remove a tagged block of text in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, sed

How can I remove all instances of tagged blocks of text in a file with sed, grep, or another program?

If I have a file which contains:

> random 
>   text 
>   // **START TEXT** 
>   internal 
>   text 
>   // **END TEXT** 
>   more 
>   random 
>   // **START TEXT** 
>   asdf 
>   // **END TEXT** 
>   text

how can I remove all blocks of text within the start/end lines, produce the following?

> random 
>   text 
>   more 
>   random 
>   text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed '\:// START TEXT:,\:// END TEXT:d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this in Perl is with Perl's flip-flop operator

```
perl -ne'print unless m{^// START TEXT}..m{^// END TEXT}'
```

x..y in Perl evaluates to true starting with x is true, and ending when y is true.  The m{} is another way to write a regular expression match so we don't have to go crazy backslashing all your forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/nawk -f
BEGIN {
startblock="^/\/\ START TEXT"
endblock="^/\/\ END TEXT"
}
{
        if(! match($0,startblock)) {
                { print }
        }
        else    {
                while ( !match($0,endblock )) {
                        getline;
                }
        }

}
```

./removeblocks < sometextfile >anothertextfile

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
perl -ne '$t=1 if /^\/\/ START TEXT/; print if !$t; $t=0 if /^\/\/ END TEXT/' < sometextfile >anothertextfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple State Machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $inblock = 0;
while (<>) {
    if (/^\/\/ START TEXT/) {
        $inblock=1;
    } elsif (/^\/\/ END TEXT/) {
        $inblock=0;
    } elsif ( ! $inblock) {
        print;
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
cat testfile | perl remove_block.pl
random
text
more
random
text
```

Although Florian's logic is sound I believe with your example, it will print `//END TEXT` with the following (malformed) input:

```
random
text
// START TEXT
internal
text
// END TEXT
// END TEXT
more
random
// START TEXT
asdf
// END TEXT
text
```

Comment: Little bit more tricky question, same sort of line by line state problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/90294/search-and-delete-lines-matching-a-pattern-along-with-comments-in-previous-line-i .  Worth reading well you are in the mindset I think.

Answer (score 0):

gawk:

```
BEGIN {
  s = 0
}

s == 1 && $0 ~ /^\/\/ END TEXT$/ {
  s = 0
  next
}

s == 1 {
  next
}

/^\/\/ START TEXT$/ {
  s = 1
  next
}

{
  print
}
```